# Jackson, custom "writer" for annotation

Tags: java, jackson

I would like to provide a specific writer and reader for one custom annotation.

I do have some classes that need a specific format for fields. The ideal solution would be to create a custom annotation and provide my own classes to read and write fields annotated with it.

```
class SampleWithSpecificFormat {

  @MyAnnotation
  private String special; // Written and read via a custom class
}
```

Do you have any resources explaining how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar feature at the moment. Here is the example. I have renamed and shortened the classes. I hope that I have understood what you are looking for and that it helps you.

**MyDto**

```java
public class MyDto {
    @MyAnnotation(value = "FooBar")
    @JsonSerialize(using = SpecialSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = SpecialDeserializer.class)
    private String special;
}
```

**MyAnnotation**

```java
// Annotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value() default "";
}
```

**SpecialSerializer**

```java
public class SpecialSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private final String annotationValue;

    public SalutationSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public SalutationSerializer(String annotationValue) {
        this.annotationValue = annotationValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String popertyValue, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        // this.annotationValue --> "FooBar"
        jsonGenerator.writeString(popertyValue + "_manipulated");
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) {
        return new SpecialSerializer(
                new MyAnnotationReader().getValue(property)
        );
    }
}
```

**SpecialDeserializer**

```java
// SpecialDeserializer
public class SpecialDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> implements ContextualDeserializer {

    private final String annotationValue;

    public SpecialDeserializer() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public SpecialDeserializer(String annotationValue) {
        this.annotationValue = annotationValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String popertyValue = jsonParser.getText();
        // this.annotationValue --> "FooBar"
        return popertyValue + "_manipulated";
    }

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property) {
        return new SpecialDeserializer(
            new MyAnnotationReader().getValue(property)
        );
    }
}
```

**MyAnnotationReader**

```java
public class MyAnnotationReader {

    public String getMap(BeanProperty property) {
        MyAnnotation annotation = property.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        return annotation.value();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's already a good entry point. However, I would like to limit the annotations to `@MyAnnotation` but can configure the mapper as much as needed.